# Fast Search for Sharepoint 2010: Incremental Crawl Memory Leak

Tags: bcs, fast-search, sharepoint-search

**Background**
My organization has been attempting to use FAST Search for Sharepoint 2010 as a search solution for our DMS. I am currently utilizing a .Net indexing connector to index a database of ~ 8 million records and their accompanying files. The full crawl, albeit time consuming (about 2 weeks), works wonderfully. It is certainly taxing on the crawl and index servers, but well within their limitations.

**Problem**
The first incremental crawl is causing a memory spike on both the crawl server (mssearch.exe) and index server (sql). I have implemented some custom logging in my connector, and I can see that it gathers all the ids and seems to only process the updated items. However, the incremental crawl never completes and, on the crawl server, mssearch.exe eventually consumes all available resources. On the index server, sqlservr.exe seems to have the same fate. Several full crawls have completed successfully, and services/servers have been restarted multiple times, but I have yet to have any luck. Full and incremental crawls work perfectly when only crawling a portion of the repository (test sizes: 30,000 & 100,000 items).

**BCS Connector**

- ReadList, ReadItem, FileStream method
- Batches files from database based on custom value (tried 100K, 500K, etc)
- Uses LastModified time stamp field for changes
- Custom security mapping
- Custom logging to indicate when batches are returned, when individual entities are processed (based on time interval), and any file stream errors

**SharePoint Environment**

- 1x WFE
- 1x Database Server
- Application Server (Crawl Server) 12GB Memory
- 1x Index Server (FAST) 16GB Memory

```
     public DMSFile ReadItem(string id)
    {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);

            DMSFile entity = new DMSFile();

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    entity.DocId = id;
                    entity.DocNumber = Int32.Parse(r["DocNum"].ToString());
                    entity.VersionNum = Int32.Parse(r["VersionNum"].ToString());
                    //etc., etc., etc.
                    entity.SecurityDescriptor = security.getSecurityDescriptor(r["DefaultSecurity"].ToString(), r["DocNum"].ToString(), r["VersionNum"].ToString());
                }
            }

            logger.writeItem(id);
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
            return entity;            
    }

    public IEnumerable<DMSFile> ReadList(ref string BatchingCookie, ref System.String HasMoreActivities)
    {
            HasMoreActivities = "false";

            batchSize = logger.getBatchCount();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);

            List<DMSFile> entityList = new List<DMSFile>(batchSize);
            if (entityList.Count > 0){entityList.Clear();}

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                    entityList.Add(new DMSFile() { 
                        DocId = rdr["DocNum"].ToString() + "." + rdr["VersionNum"].ToString(),
                        LastModified = DateTime.Parse(rdr["LastEdited"].ToString()).ToUniversalTime()
                    });
                }
            }


            if (entityList.Count == batchSize){
                HasMoreActivities = "true";
                BatchingCookie = entityList[entityList.Count - 1].DocId;
            }

            logger.writeAll(entityList.Count.ToString(), BatchingCookie);

            DMSFile[] entityArray = entityList.ToArray();

            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();

            return entityArray;
    }

    public Stream ReadItemStream(string id)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);

        connection.Open();
        byte[] bytes = null;
            //SQL only return document location
        string fileLocation = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();


        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int length = Int32.Parse(fs.Length.ToString());
                bytes = new byte[length];
                fs.Read(bytes, 0, length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception fileError){logger.logError(fileError.Message + "     " + fileLocation2);}

        return new MemoryStream(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: Have you profiled your connector code? Could the "leak" be in your code? Remeber that .net don't release memory unless a variable is not referenced any more and it won't garbage collect unless needed either.

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP 
I added some code to the post. This is the 4th or 5th version of the connector, each one returning less and less. If there's a glaring detail I am missing, I would love to know. I think I am disposing of all superfluous data, yet only small steps in memory management have been obtained. That said, the full crawl completes every time with (presumably) adequate efficiency. Thus, further complicating the issue. (Note* the "custom logging" was only recently added. This problem has existed long before it).

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP   Sorry, I didn't reply to your initial question. Yes, I have analyzed the code, which does highlight the need to dispose the sql connections after closing (a silly mistake). However, this still does not explain why I would only be experiencing issues during the incremental crawl (seemingly, a less intensive process).

Comment: Don't see any obvious errors except I would not use an SqlDataAdapter, but rather a SqlDataReader so as not to load more data into memory than needed at any given time. Also you can initialize the List<DMSFile>(batchSize) to avoid resizing it as grows. Initial size is 4 if I'm not mistaken. You might also be able to wrap the return out from ReadList with a yield return to optimize it even more.

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP . I made the proposed changes, but it seems to only have a negligible effect on memory consumption.

I am still struggling to complete incremental crawls, which spend hours on the gathering process. ReadList is only being called every 30-60 minutes when batching 1 million items per call. This is occurring even when there are no updates to process (no ReadItem). The sql cmd only takes a few seconds to return records.

Also, the gatherer is storing several GBs of information in the temp folder. Is this normal for incrementals? Once again, works great on smaller repository.

Comment: If you haven't, disable ifilters om the SP crawl boxes as per http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc130ec2-fc86-4a8f-936e-9b00f5403d85/how-can-i-increase-the-speed-of-crawling-data-with-my-net-assembly-connector?forum=fastsharepoint

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP   I have disabled the SP iFilters, but the change seems minimal. Mind you, the next crawl seemed to be crawling a bit better, but it still does not solve my memory issues. My current incremental crawl has taken 5+ hours to crawl roughly 47K files and is spiking out on memory (MSSearch 11GB). This will occasionally drop (only to spike again), but the crawl does not seem to be progressing.

I updated my code above and my xml can be found [here](http://goo.gl/snRH4N)

Comment: I haven't have time to look into this, but could you try to create a console application which uses your code, and run the same logic. Call readlist, and readitem. And then check the memory usage of your console app.

Comment: @Mikael-SharePointMVP   Sorry about the long delay. I have created a console application using the same logic, but everything worked as expected (utilizing a very reasonable amount of memory). However, this comes with the caveat of not knowing the ins-and-outs of how mssearch handles the assembly. Still, it doesn't explain why I would only experience these issues on incremental crawls. Any further suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm blank, and seems something going on with mssearch. I would file a support ticket on this.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fruitless research, I stumbled upon this KB article describing a very similar issue with the FAST search solution:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2601211

It would seem that the crawl box was gathering a lot more information than necessary, creating huge entities. After installing the hotfix: Memory usage decreased significantly, the 'Unable to Access Object' errors disappeared, and the crawl was able to complete.

We started experiencing issues with the next incremental crawl, but I believe those are environmental and unrelated to the original issue.